# window.opener.someGlobalJavaScriptVariable is always undefined when using Chrome v37+

Tags: javascript, asp.net, undefined, window.open, ascx

I am facing an issue with window.open and window.opener.someGlobalJavaScriptVariable.

I have two *.ascx pages that are parent and its child page. They are located in the same folder.

The parent page will call window.open to show the child page under a window.
And the problem is that the window.opener.someGlobalJavaScriptVariable is always underfined in child page. I cannot recieve my expected arguments which I have sent from the parent page.

(I am developing these code on Chrome ver 37+ so that I cannot use window.showModalDialog in parent page and window.dialogArguments in child page.)

Please help me out of this problem. I really dont know the reason why I got it. It spends a day of mine.

Here is parent page code:

```
function parentFunction(fileCode)
{
    var args = new Array();
    args["fileCode"] = fileCode;
    var url = "childPage.aspx";
    var WinSettings = "center:yes; resizable:yes; dialogWidth:450px; dialogHeight:350px;scrollbars=yes;"
    var w;
    var h;
    var resizable = "no";
    var scroll = "no";
    var status = "no";

    // get the modal specs
    var mdattrs = WinSettings.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < mdattrs.length; i++) {
        var mdattr = mdattrs[i].split(":");

        var n = mdattr[0];
        var v = mdattr[1];
        if (n) { n = n.trim().toLowerCase(); }
        if (v) { v = v.trim().toLowerCase(); }

        if (n == "dialogheight") {
            h = v.replace("px", "");
        } else if (n == "dialogwidth") {
            w = v.replace("px", "");
        } else if (n == "resizable") {
            resizable = v;
        } else if (n == "scroll") {
            scroll = v;
        } else if (n == "status") {
            status = v;
        }
    }

    var left = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight / 2) - (h / 2);
    args = window.open(url, args, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=' + status + ', menubar=no, scrollbars=' + scroll + ', resizable=' + resizable + ', copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
```

And the child page code (childPage.ascx):

```
function childFunction() {
    var args = new Array();
    args = window.opener.someGlobalJavaScriptVariable;
    //args is always undefined at this step
}
```

**[UPDATE01][Updating new information after applying a suggestion of WhiteHat]**

I tried applying the solution as WhiteHat suggested and I still got the problem. My expected argument is still undefined in child page.

Please see the code of two pages to get more details.

ParentPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ParentPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.ParentPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <div>
         <input type="button" onclick="parentFunction('A0');" value="Show Child Page" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function parentFunction(fileCode) {
            var args = new Array();
            args["fileCode"] = fileCode;
            var url = "childPage.aspx";
            var WinSettings = "center:yes; resizable:yes; dialogWidth:450px; dialogHeight:350px;scrollbars=yes;"
            var w;
            var h;
            var resizable = "no";
            var scroll = "no";
            var status = "no";

            // get the modal specs
            var mdattrs = WinSettings.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < mdattrs.length; i++) {
                var mdattr = mdattrs[i].split(":");

                var n = mdattr[0];
                var v = mdattr[1];
                if (n) { n = n.trim().toLowerCase(); }
                if (v) { v = v.trim().toLowerCase(); }

                if (n == "dialogheight") {
                    h = v.replace("px", "");
                } else if (n == "dialogwidth") {
                    w = v.replace("px", "");
                } else if (n == "resizable") {
                    resizable = v;
                } else if (n == "scroll") {
                    scroll = v;
                } else if (n == "status") {
                    status = v;
                }
            }

            var left = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth / 2) - (w / 2);
            var top = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight / 2) - (h / 2);
            args = window.open(url, args, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=' + status + ', menubar=no, scrollbars=' + scroll + ', resizable=' + resizable + ', copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            var myargs = args;
            var mynum = 777;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ChildPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.ChildPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
         <input type="button" onclick="closeWindow();" value="Show args from Parent Page" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function closeWindow()
        {
            alert("window.opener.myargs =" + window.opener.myargs);
            alert("window.opener.mynum =" + window.opener.mynum);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to window.open

The point is, you define a variable in JavaScript, then just reference it by window.opener.yourVariable

Read this, last post...

http://forums.asp.net/t/1267365.aspx?window+open+and+window+dialogArguments+in+javascript

Comment: Sorry for crappy answer on my mobile and can't figure out how to format

Comment: I tried applying the idea from the post you suggested and the problem still appears. Where am I wrong when applying it? I have updated more info, please have a look my post above to get more details.

Comment: In the parent, define the variables outside the scope of the function, I will provide better example once I get to a computer...

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat, it works fine in only case that two pages are located in the same folder. BUT, I found another case that the solution cannot work, two pages are stored in different location. For example, parent page locates at "myweb\js\parentpage.aspx" and child one locates at "myweb\usercontrols\childpage.aspx"..

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat, I solved the second problem myself. I accepted your answer.